# Portable washer: Is this size of converter wrong?

Tags: faucet, sink, adapter

I bought a portable washer from Amazon and the adapter + diverter + hose to connect to my kitchen faucet.

This adapter is for Female G1/2 to Male 3/4'' but it doesn’t fit.

Can someone please tell me what size I should buy?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your faucet is female so you need male to female faucet, not female to male.  The part of the faucet on the bottom that has the letters GPM will turn/screw off.  Get an adapter that matches.

Comment: i'm more certain than not that that's indeed the right part, but it might be reverse threaded, so try lefty-tighty and see if it grabs.

Comment: @isherwood  I could be confusing it, but my understanding is the aerator has the male thread going into the faucets female thread.  The aerator would need removing for the adapter to attach to the faucet.  I think there are aerators with a push to connect design, so you only push the hose onto them.  That aerator looks like it threads into the inside of the faucet, instead of the outside.

Comment: You ideally should get something like [this](https://www.amazon.com/Diverter-Bathroom-Connection-Portable-Dishwasher/dp/B08P6LPMJD/ref=sr_1_7) (I didn't do any research, that's a random one) that includes various sized adapters and allows you to keep the dishwasher connected and use your sink.  If you don't want that, the comment from crisp659 is correct.